# Passing object to the JCL-loaded class

Tags: java, jar, classloader, dynamic-class-loaders

I have really tricky problem. I have kinda container which can run custom JAR with the method which has a class `ComponentContext` as a parameter. After loading I want to invoke this method with the reflection but there is a problem - I must use the same class loader (JCL in this case) to create `ComponentContext`. See the code:

```
JclObjectFactory factory = JclObjectFactory.getInstance();
Object context = factory.create(jcl, "org.hive.lib.component.ComponentContextImpl");

Method setConfigDirMethod = context.getClass().getMethod("initialize", File.class, File.class);
setConfigDirMethod.invoke(context, configDir, workspace);

Method method = instance.getClass().getMethod("initialize", context.getClass());
method.invoke(instance, context);
```

And when I'm trying to pass context created in container like this

```
ComponentContextImpl c = new ComponentContext();
```

It fails with `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` because of another classloader.

It means that my container depends on class from the JAR, it drives me crazy. It there a way to pass my own `ComponentContext` (not instantiated from the JAR) to the method `initialize`?

PS - JAR was assembled with `assembly:single`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved as marking shared library as `provided`